# make selected according to custom attr by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am want to marked as selected according to custom attr.

My select code:

```
<select name="user_country" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Select Your Country" id="user_country">
<option data-iso2="in" value="1">India</option>
<option data-iso2="al" value="2">Albania</option>
<option data-iso2="dz" value="3">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Here i am want to mark as selected by `data-iso2`

Something like this:

```
var iso2 = 'in';
$('#user_country attr[data-iso2=iso2]').attr('selected','selected');
```

here i am want to **select** option where `data-iso2="in"`

Comment: $(".form-contro").find("option [data-iso2='2']").select()

Comment: var value = "a1";
$(".form-control").val(value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `option` from the `data-iso2` value you want to get it selected:

```js
var selVal = 'al';
$('#user_country').find('[data-iso2='+selVal+']').attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="user_country" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Select Your Country" id="user_country">
<option data-iso2="af" value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option data-iso2="al" value="2">Albania</option>
<option data-iso2="dz" value="3">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly. i will make as accepted after 7 minutes

Comment: @ShivSingh glad to help